# Visual Studio 2010 crashes after build

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a VB.Net windows forms application that has been around for a very long time. I am working the project in Visual Studio 2010 Premium, on my Windows 7 x64 workstation. Everything has been going along fine till a couple days ago. No every time I build this project Visual Studio 2010 crashes.

The only thing i have to go on is this from another Visual Studio 2010 instance that attached the debugger to the dieing process.

```
...
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x177c) has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xc44) has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
The program '[4224] devenv.exe: Native' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

No one else on my team has this issue, and I don't have problems with any other projects.

This is .Net 4.0.

Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated,

Beezler

Comment: I have narrowed this further. I have found that if I first delete the OBJ and BIN folders, Visual Studio will not crash. I did get an error when I used an older version of the project file indicating it could not open the pdb file. I am pursuing that now.

Comment: I've got pretty much the same problem.  The Visual Basic Winforms project I'm working on has been around Since Visual Studio 2003, but never gave us this much trouble until Visual Studio 2010.  I need to be lucky just to get a debugging run started.  It seems like the problem originates in the UI project in my solution (which includes four projects - the UI, a class library, a custom control library, and an installer).  Has anyone figured this out?  I know if it gets submitted to Microsoft, they'll just say they can't repro and drop it, but's it's a real problem.

Answer (score 5):

It might be wise to start VS with the /safemode parameter.

I also had this problem and I solved it by uninstalling the Achievements extension.

Comment: Wow thank you. I really liked the Achievements extensions but after uninstalled the problem got away. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the Achievements extension. Fixed my problem. I can't believe how much that extension can slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any modifications whatsoever to the solution/projects/code that are different from the team members not experiencing the crash?  Have you tried getting a fresh-cut of the source to a different directory and trying to build that?

Another thing to look at would be to disable any add-ins/extensions you might have installed.

Comment: Not much different between the two. I do have the same version on my hard drive as everyone else. I did get latest, etc... to verify.

Comment: If you don't have any pending changes, try forcing the get to replace all local files even if no changes exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with C++ projects. They ran fine for a while, then all of a sudden just started crashing on every build. This fixed it for me:

To fix: click start, type "cmd" into the search box, right click "cmd.exe" in the search results, select "run as admin", then run this command: regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

Reference: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533194/crash-while-compile-an-extremely-simple-c-project

If that doesn't work, the plugin AnkHSVN is known to cause the same problem. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/11/if-you-are-seeing-intermittent-crashes-with-vs-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is weird and i've also faced a similar issue like that. First i add a watch to a class. and when i try to drill to details of class collection, process terminates and debugging stops.

I've figured out that, it is giving stackoverflow error code. Base of the exception was just because of infinite loop.

So i re-checked all collections twice to find the property that causes a loop. like
int a {get {return MethodThatAlsoReturnsA();}

hope it helps s.o.